# android free scrolling view

Tags: android, webview, scrollview, android-contentprovider

I have a scrollview with both horizontal and vertical scrolling but I would like this activity to scroll as freely as webviews do. Currently with my default implementation it is a very jerky scrolling, and it cannot scroll diagonally. It will scroll left and right, but you cannot scroll up and down unless you stop scrolling (lift your finger up) wait, and then scroll up and down.

What is the best solution for this? I do not want to implement a contentprovider + webview for this solution.

Thank you

Comment: When you say jerky, does the rest of the app run slow/lag in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For diagonal scrolling, there has been some opensource code created in a custom class [here](http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/). Note that you should read the comments, as they include important information about the XML file implementation of this custom 2D scroll class. As for the jerkiness problem, if it persists after this implementation, please answer my comment under your question.

Comment: Vinay, I determined the initial jerkiness was due to the size of the image. But even with a smaller image, the scrolling isn't as good or as flexible as a webview's is

Comment: Ok, so the app itself isn't overburdened on the main UI thread right? That is, you don't have lots of long tasks that wait on the main thread (i.e. your application connects to a server and sends and receives data from it on the main thread before anything else can happen). The reason I ask is because this could make the application itself laggy and not necessarily have anything to do with your image/ScrollView. Also, how did you determine it's the image? If that's the case, could you please provide some relevant XML and Java code? Hopefully I can help you from there.

Comment: I determined it was the image by lowering the resolution of the image and watching the scrolling motion behave better

Comment: Ok cool, so maybe it is the image. Please provide the relevant code in that case, and we'll move from there.

Comment: Vinay, because I'll also need tap-to-zoom and double-tap to zoom, as well as diagonal scrolling, I am just going to implement the webview instead. Thank you.  It also looks like the custom class you provided uses a lot of RAM as the author mentions so I wouldn't find this favorable.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help much man. Out of curiosity, is there any reason why you initially excluded the idea of using a WebView?

Comment: Yes, was determining the time it would take to implement and the priority of features.

Comment: Ah ok, well I'm glad that you found an equally acceptable alternative.

Comment: Linked blog post has been removed